# Splash Screen Mobile

Tags: android, apache-cordova, phonegap-buillder

Estou tentando definir Splash Screen no meu apk desenvolvido com Cordova porém não estou conseguindo, estou seguindo a documentação [disponível no site oficial](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/config_ref/images.html#link-2) porem não funciona, as minhas dúvidas são as seguintes:
O arquivo config.xml que preciso alterar é o primeiro que fica dentro da pasta do projeto?

Na documentação eles passam este código http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/config_ref/images.html#link-2`

Comment: Sim, é o config.xml principal. Também não consegui sucesso com o plugin de splash. O que faço é criar um timeout no javascript para redirecionar para outra página, assim gero a sensação de que há splash. O usuário não percebe que por baixo dos panos é isso. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: @LeonardoMarinho valeu pela ajuda, pode ser uma solução temporário no meu caso mas realmente preciso conseguir fazer com que funciona o plugin nativo para isto

Comment: Bom... pelo menos temporariamente já da uma força. Abraços.

Answer (score 3):

Bom, não sei se você já fez a instalação do puglin de SplashScreen que consta na documentação do Cordova, caso já tenha instalado o puglin, o próximo passo seria adicionar as tags de preferência ao documento "config.xml".No caso :

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>

<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="1000"/> //Aqui coloque o tempo do delay.
```

OBS.Lembre-se que as **preferences** devem estar dentro da Tag **Widget**.

Ainda dentro da pasta **Resources** irá conter duas pastas **drawable-port** para orientação em portrait e a pasta **drawable-land** para orientação em landscape.

Basta copiar seu arquivo de imagem para cada uma dessas pastas, removendo os arquivos .png default que o Cordova gera e substituindo pelos seus, basta renomear ao final o seu arquivo para **screen.png**.

No meu caso consegui rodar a Splash Screen normalmente, espero ter sido útil.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente muito obrigado.